# Refund of iOS in-app purchase - triggered by developer, not end user

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

**Case:**

Our iOS app offers selling of custom made recipe packages that would be created for each user specifically. For example - user buys package of recipes, but for each user this package would be created individually, based on users preferences and needs, by someone from the app team. This package should be created in 5 days for example. If app team fails to create this package and deliver to end user in 5 days, automatic refund should be triggered and end user should receive money back that he spent on this in app purchase, thus invalidating purchased custom package.

**Problem:**

Is this kind of scenario even possible in Apple / iOS world? Can app developer trigger refund process of one specific purchase that end user made? If user isn't satisfied with specific purchase, could app developer trigger this is refund process if he has reference to transaction receipt?

P.S. We aren't really selling custom recipe packages, this was just an example scenario to help to understand this refund scenario case. ;)

**EDIT:**

If such scenario isn't possible via Apple refund, are there some examples of this kind of purchase model, implemented in some other way? It's hard to wrap my mind that only way for end user to get refund for something is to write Apple and that also needs to be done by user itself.

Comment: This sounds like more of a business process-related question and should be directed to the apple/iOS world. Here at SO you would want to post more programming-specific questions.

Comment: @beauXjames i agree, i just started this question with hope that Apple actually would offer StoreKit API for this kind of model.

Answer (score 8):

If you get paid using Apple services (in-app purchases) then NO, it isn't possible for an Apple Developer (business or individual) to refund App Store customers.

The only option is to direct customers to [iTunes Store Customer Support](http://www.apple.com/support/itunes/) as officially stated in the iTunes Connect screenshot below:

[image]

To increase the chances for your customers in getting refunded you could provide them with an e-mail stating that you would like them to receive a refund which they could show to the iTunes Support employee.

As a colleague stated, an option would be to use an external payment processor like PayPal which would allow you to manage refunds, but I think this will greatly increase the work needed since you will need to manage almost everything regarding payments on your own.

Also note that this option is highly restricted by Apple to only physical services or goods and sometimes Apple does not approve apps providing services through third-party payment processors. So.. you should be very careful what path you choose to take.

If the recipes you're providing to your customers are in digital format and users receive them in your app, you can be 100% sure that Apple will force you to use the in-app purchase system.

Answer (score 2):

> If such scenario isn't possible via Apple refund, are there some
>   examples of this kind of purchase model, implemented in some other
>   way?

In some cases you can use payment through PayPal (for example). We did it in our application where we had to take money of users and return it after a certain period. Check if you case is suitable for using third-party payment systems. Because (for example) Apple will restrict your app if you want to sell in-game content via Paypal, not with in-app purchase.

Comment: How to check in my apple account that my customer has paid to me for my app in app purchase

Answer (score 1):

One very simple alternative would be to have your users buy virtual currency in your app that they can then spend on their recipe-package-orders. Since you are managing their virtual currency account balance, you can easily refund, give volume-discounts, etc. as you please. The only thing that will still be hard then is to have users return their virtual currency to get back their actual money.

Answer (score 0):

There is no api for allowing users to refund a purchase (otherwise guess what can happen).

More info [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/StoreKitGuide/Chapters/Subscriptions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008267-CH7-SW5)

Comment: You could list some more information in your post itself, instead of only posting a link ;) Basically, it seems from this information that your best course of action is to redirect the customer to Apple's customer service and have it refunded there.

Comment: What more information can be given? the link directly shows Apple's cancellation policy which answers his question if it is possible

Comment: Just a summary that might be applicable to this situation makes the answer a lot more useful.

Comment: What summary? cancellation via the api is not possible. period. He can can create his own payment system but I don't believe it will be accepted by Apple